# Oracle SQL Developer Debugger Automatically Committing Problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I debug a procedure in Oracle SQL Developer, if I don't terminate the debugging before it finishes, it commits after the completion. But this is not what I want actually. I have to either terminate debugging before it finishes, or need to write a rollback before the last DML. But what I want is that, SQL Developer should rollback automatically as soon as debugging ends.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith ?

Comment: Yeah. This is a question that I also wanted to learn. @thatjeffsmith

Comment: FWIW, this appears to be a feature of the Oracle PL/SQL debugger, as I see similar behavior when using PL/SQL Developer from Allround Automations.

Comment: Try adding a rollback; to the end of the anonymous block you see when kicking off your debug session - assuming of course your sp doesn't do commit or DDL itself